# Is there a word for the various "subevents" at an event?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Is there a general word for the "subevents" at an event of some sort? For instance, at a conference, I guess I could probably use "talk" or "presentation"; at a fair I could perhaps use "presentation" or "demonstration", and so on – but is there a common word that I could use for **any** "subevent" at any kind of event? I've thought about "feature, "item" and "slot", but when I look up these words in dictionaries, I don't find unequivocal support for either of them in this context.

Examples:

The first [REQUESTED WORD] starts at 9.

There are many interesting [REQUESTED WORD] on today's programme.

Answer (score 2):

I would use 'activities', 'stuff' or 'things'. But it depends on the event.

Comment: Ah... yes – I like "activity"! Could that be used even about someone giving a paper or the like though? Or can it only be used about more active stuff?

Comment: @Lillatanten "Activities" is a very general term. It could, I suppose,be used for giving a paper, but a more specific term such as "paper" or "presentation" would in most cases be better. Unless one is talking about a wide range of different events, why struggle to find a word that can apply to all types, but will inb many cases not be a **good** fit?

Comment: @DavidSiegel Thing is, I need it for an event comprising activities ranging all the way from traditional presentations to trying out limbo dancing... so, as you see, I do need a very general word. Would you say "feature" would be better than activity?

Comment: @Lillatanten I see. In that case either "feature" or "activity" sounds quite good to me, and I would have no grounds for preferring one over the other. Good luck with the event.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Thank you – both for input and good wishes :)

Answer (score 0):

Long meetings or events often have breakout sessions, or just **sessions**; generally they are short chunks of time dedicated to one group or topic. The event agenda might even be organized in a grid so that people can see at a glance what their choices are in any given time slot.

For example, the massive CES trade show has a "[schedule of sessions and events](https://www.ces.tech/schedule.aspx)" to help attendees plan their time.

The UK CRF Society has [a planning guide to help attendees get the most out of the tracks of parallel sessions](https://www.ukcrfnetwork.co.uk/2019/06/07/select-your-conference-parallel-session/) they can select from.